# Why is static void Main(string[] args) at the bottom of this program?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm learning C# and it says in a tutorial "When you run your programme, C# looks for a Method called Main. It uses the Main Method as the starting point for your programmes. It then executes any code between those two curly brackets. "

But on another tutorial site it has a slice of code that says

```
using System;
namespace RectangleApplication
{
   class Rectangle 
   {
     // member variables
     double length;
     double width;

     public void Acceptdetails()
     {
        length = 4.5;    
        width = 3.5;
     }

     public double GetArea()
     {
        return length * width; 
     }

     public void Display()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
        Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
        Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
     }
   }

class ExecuteRectangle 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
     {
         Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
         r.Acceptdetails();
         r.Display();
         Console.ReadLine(); 
      }
   }
}
```

With the Main method below the other methods. (I'm new at this so I assume that public void acceptdetails, get area, display, are all methods). My question is, why isn't it at the top right below namespace? I put the method up there and it worked the same and checked other posts on here and it said maybe the author was just trying to put emphasis on other things, but I don't fully understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you put it. Main() is always the entry point when the program first runs. Functions such as Main() can be anywhere in the code and the compiler will start running there, assuming it compiles and syntax is fine.

It looks like the author of the above code purposely put the Main() function at the bottom of that source code to illustrate this point.

Comment: What do you mean by "entry point"? Wouldn't the entry point be at the top?

Comment: The entry point is just where execution starts, which by default is the 1st line inside the Main() function. The first thing that happens here is space is allocated for a new rectangle object in the line Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

Comment: Ooh. So it starts regardless of where it is at Main, and then because the next line is the name of the first class, then it jumps up to that first class?

also, i read somewhere it says Main is used in like 1% of programs, why is that?

Comment: Correct! Keep going and once you learn control flow, basic program structure, and functions it will make much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

`Main()` is a 'special' function that serves as the entry point for the program, even if it does not occur first in the code listing.  In the code above, the programmer put the declaration of the `Rectangle` class first, but that doesn't affect which code runs first.
`Main()` runs first. That's the way the language is designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your confusion is if c# executes the statement line by line why the main method is not in the beginning. Well, it doesn't have to be because that's what the compiler does for you. Compiler looks for the entry point to find out the first line of execution. It looks it up by the name "main" method . That's one of the reason why you can't have more than one method in your application. Because compiler will be " confused" and will not able to decide where to enter first.

And once it enters the main method , it starts executing line by line. And if it finds any method call , it again goes and starts looking for the method name, enters the method, starts executing line by line and comes back to the main method at the point where it left.

Hence , as you might have seen, regardless of where you put your code in your code files, compiler still executes line by line.

Of course , I have omitted the advanced cases of parallel programming or asynchronous operations.